# JS array.map with costly async function

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await

I have a set of users. I need to call "`costlyEncryptionFunction`" on each `user.id`, but I don't want to call "`costlyEncryptionFunction`" multiple times on the same `user.id`.

Here is a working example:

```
const costlyEncryptionFunction = async (id) => {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(id + 1000)
    }, 1000)
  })
}  

let users = [
  {id: 1, item: 1},
  {id: 1, item: 2},
  {id: 2, item: 5},
  {id: 2, item: 6}
]

let currentUserId
users.map(async (user) => {

  let encryptedUserId
  if(!currentUserId || currentUserId != user.id){
    currentUserId = user.id
    encryptedUserId = await costlyEncryptionFunction(currentUserId)
  }

  if(encryptedUserId){
    console.log(`inside: ${encryptedUserId} ${user.item} ... do more stuff` )
  }
})
```

The output reads

```
inside: 1001 1 ... do more stuff
inside: 1002 5 ... do more stuff
```

I am trying to have my output read:

```
inside: 1001 1 ... do more stuff
inside: 1001 2 ... do more stuff
inside: 1002 5 ... do more stuff
inside: 1002 6 ... do more stuff
```

Does anyone have a solution to this, other than calling "`costlyEncryptionFunction`" and repeating the same `userId` multiple times?

Comment: Memoize the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic way to do this is to use an object as a cache:

```
const cache = {};

const costlyEncryptionFunction = async (id) => {
    const existing = cache[id];
    if (existing) return Promise.resolve(existing);
    
    return new Promise((res) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const encrypted = id + 1000;
            cache[id] = encrypted;
            res(encrypted);
        }, 1000)
    })
}

let users = [
    { id: 1, item: 1 },
    { id: 1, item: 2 },
    { id: 2, item: 5 },
    { id: 2, item: 6 }
]

let currentUserId
users.map(async (user) => {

    let encryptedUserId
    if (!currentUserId || currentUserId != user.id) {
        currentUserId = user.id
        encryptedUserId = await costlyEncryptionFunction(currentUserId)
    }

    if (encryptedUserId) {
        console.log(`inside: ${encryptedUserId} ${user.item} ... do more stuff`)
    }
})
```

If your target environment supports it, you can use a `Map`:

```
const cache = new Map();

const costlyEncryptionFunction = async (id) => {
    const existing = cache.has(id) ? cache.get(id) : undefined;
    if (existing) return Promise.resolve(existing);

    return new Promise((res) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const encrypted = id + 1000;
            cache.set(id, encrypted) = encrypted;
            res(encrypted);
        }, 1000)
    })
}

let users = [
    { id: 1, item: 1 },
    { id: 1, item: 2 },
    { id: 2, item: 5 },
    { id: 2, item: 6 }
]

let currentUserId
users.map(async (user) => {

    let encryptedUserId
    if (!currentUserId || currentUserId != user.id) {
        currentUserId = user.id
        encryptedUserId = await costlyEncryptionFunction(currentUserId)
    }

    if (encryptedUserId) {
        console.log(`inside: ${encryptedUserId} ${user.item} ... do more stuff`)
    }
})
```

This is more or less what utility libraries do under the hood with their memoize methods, though they typically offer features such as multiple parameters, which complicates the implementation a bit.

Comment: "costlyEncryptionFunction" is obviously not the real encryption function... but yeah that idea will work. I will put a wrapper function around the encryption function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Node.js, You could use the ramda package to memoize the function

```
const {identity, memoizeWith} = require('ramda');

const costlyEncryptionFunction = async (id) => {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(id + 1000)
    }, 1000)
  })
}  

const memoizedCostlyFunction = (identity, costlyEncryptionFunction)

let users = [
  {id: 1, item: 1},
  {id: 1, item: 2},
  {id: 2, item: 5},
  {id: 2, item: 6}
]

let currentUserId
users.map(async (user) => {

  let encryptedUserId
  if(true ){
    currentUserId = user.id
    // encryptedUserId = await costlyEncryptionFunction(currentUserId)
    encryptedUserId = await memoizedCostlyFunction(currentUserId)
  }

  if(encryptedUserId){
    console.log(`inside: ${encryptedUserId} ${user.item} ... do more stuff` )
  }
})
```